# I am getting same value for every time in rand() in C

Tags: c, random

In this program, I need to take 2 random numbers and one of them must be equal to 3.  To make them, the `randomSet` function works with a while loop, but the problem is in the main function: the loop gives me same 2 numbers every time. How do I get different numbers on each iteration?

```
int randomSet(int temp[])
{
  while (temp[0] != 3 && temp[1] != 3)
         {
            temp[0] =rand()%4;
            temp[1] =rand()%4;
         }
}
```

the main function is

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int temp[2];
    int x =0,y =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        randomSet(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: İts same again, i initialize the temp array but it dldnt change the result

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `temp` before passing it to `randomSet()`, so its contents are *indeterminate*, causing `while (temp[0] != 3 && temp[1] != 3)` to have *undefined behavior*.

I suggest you change `randomSet()` to use a `do..while` loop instead so that you populate `temp` 1 time before you then start analyzing its content, eg:

```
int randomSet(int temp[])
{
    do
    {
        temp[0] = rand() % 4;
        temp[1] = rand() % 4;
    }
    while (temp[0] != 3 && temp[1] != 3);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much :))) it solved the problem thanks again.

Comment: `(temp[0] != 3 && temp[1] != 3)` and `(!(temp[0] == 3 || temp[1] == 3))` are entirely equivalent.

Comment: The termination condition of the do while loop always results in the two values equaling 3.

Comment: The original loop condition is fine — though it should indeed be a `do { … } while (…);` loop and not a `while (…) { … }` loop.  It terminates when one or the other of the values is 3 (or both, but it only checks the first).

Comment: You are right, I misread the original code. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily instrument the code and see what goes on.  As already pointed out, the key necessary change is that you must determine two random values on entry to the function before checking whether either (or both) of them is 3.  That is easily achieved with a `do { … } while (…);` loop.

Despite suggestions to the contrary, the loop condition in the question is OK, though it needs to be converted from a `while` loop.  The loop continues while neither element is 3; as soon as one or the other is 3 (or both are 3, but it only checks the first element, `temp[0]`), the loop stops.

For example (file `rand19.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static void randomSet(int temp[])
{
    do
    {
        temp[0] = rand() % 4;
        temp[1] = rand() % 4;
        printf("--  %d  %d\n", temp[0], temp[1]);
    } while (temp[0] != 3 && temp[1] != 3);
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int temp[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        randomSet(temp);
        printf("%d:  %d  %d\n", i, temp[0], temp[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example runs:

```
$ rand19
--  2  0
--  1  3
0:  1  3
--  0  3
1:  0  3
--  0  3
2:  0  3
--  2  2
--  0  1
--  3  0
3:  3  0
--  2  0
--  2  0
--  1  0
--  1  0
--  2  3
4:  2  3
$ sleep 60
$ rand19
--  3  3
0:  3  3
--  1  3
1:  1  3
--  1  0
--  3  1
2:  3  1
--  3  2
3:  3  2
--  0  2
--  1  1
--  1  2
--  0  1
--  1  2
--  2  1
--  3  1
4:  3  1
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomSet(int temp[])
{
  while (1)
         {
            x = rand()%4;
            y = rand()%4;
            if (x < 3 && y < 3) 
            {
               temp[0] = x;
               temp[1] = y;
            }
            else
               break;
         }
}
```